# POP3 connection string for livemail or gmail?

Tags: pop3

I have a third party application that requires a 'POP 3 connection string'.
I'd never heard of such a thing but apparently it looks something like this :

```
 Line 314; connection string: {pop3.live.com:995/pop3/ssl}INBOX
```

or

```
 {outlook.XXXXXXXX.net:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX
```

The problem is I can't seem to create a connection string for some either Live mail or Gmail that works.

The application - (which is trying to connect to the POP3 account to process email bounces) - just gives an error.

I just cant seem to find ANY documentation anywhere about POP 3 connection strings. I assume it must be some kind of standard.

The tech support for the product in question said "Ask Microsoft for the connection string for Windows Live mail". I don't think its worth the effort trying to ask - but hoped someone here could shed some light on the issue.

Perhaps a POP3 connection testing tool would be useful too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the "POP 3 connection strings" part, maybe this RFC can help you : [RFC 2384 - POP URL Scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2384) :

> A POP URL is of the general form:
>
> `pop://<user>;auth=<auth>@<host>:<port>`

About the URL for gmail... Not that simple ; maybe the code example in [this article][2] can help ; there is a comment in the code that says :

```
/*
 * Access Gmail POP account
 */
/*
 $message_file='pop3://'.$user.':'.$password.'@pop.gmail.com:995/1?tls=1&debug=1&html_debug=1';
  */
```

With a bit of luck, maybe something like this could work in your application too ?

Comment: its looking like the issue is actually related to PHP not being able to make an SSL connection or something like that. i'm not quite sure whats going on there but first step was to verify the URL format was correct. thanksa a lot